# How to delete Row n + (Number of Rows) in Excel whilst WorkSheet is hidden

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove records from a WorkSheet that is hidden and do not want to un-hide it to do so.

If it was visible, I would:

```
Sheets("vwReportA").Select
Rows("15:15").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Clear
```

How can I achieve this whilst worksheet is hidden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Select` like this is not necassary.  See [this answer for ideas on avoiding Select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/445425)

Try this

```
Dim sh as WorkSheet
Dim rng as Range
Set sh = Sheets("vwReportA")
Set rng = sh.[A15]
sh.Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Clear
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("vwReportA").Rows("15:15")
Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Clear
```